# Issue npm install with public wifi

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I have Bought new laptop with windows 10 and I installed `nodejs` with `angular 10`, the problem I face when I try to `run ng new myproject`, is take a lot time to install dependencies and hanging with no continue.

I tried these solutions but didn't work:

```
npm cache clean --force
ng new myproject --skip-install ==> npm install --verbose
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

I am using `public wifi` that security type is `Open`
Does this affect that?

Comment: In my experiences, if you're using public wifi, everything slows down.  Also, you're prone to security risks as well- other people can see the data coming through if they know where to look.

Comment: @NadineRose what should I do then?

Comment: Get on a secure network with faster internet.  I think these problems should go away.

Comment: @NadineRose Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem that it is the public WiFi has a restriction on the network, when I tried connect my laptop to another network(3G network) its worked perfectly.

Comment: What restriction prevented you from accessing npm registry? I'm having the same problem but with my home wifi. It works perfectly except for my development server. My iPhone hotspot works though :(

Comment: Because the internet provider has many security issues, Try another provider and mostly will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where on my home wifi I wasn't able to install npm packages and terminal just hags. The odd things is like you've said, it's working on mobile hotspot from my phone.
What I did is **updating router firmware** (Tenda AC2100) and now it's working perfectly fine so far.

However, you cannot update the public wifi router firmware, but leaving this commnet here might help someone else with similar issue.